# PostgreSQL: Query to retrieve the top 2 and bottom 2 rows including equals

Tags: sql, postgresql

What I'm trying to accomplish is a query to retrieve the top 2 purchased products and the least 2 purchased products alongside the product_id, but is has to include products that have been purchased the same number of times.

This is the table I'm using

```
CREATE TABLE Orderlines(
    ORDERLINEID serial NOT NULL,
    ORDERID integer NOT NULL,
    PROD_ID integer NOT NULL,
    QUANTITY text NOT NULL,
    ORDERDATE date NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(ORDERLINEID,ORDERID)    
);
```

And this is the semi-finished query that sorts the products by the times they've been purchased, including their prod_id.

```
SELECT PROD_ID, COUNT(*) AS c
FROM Orderlines
GROUP BY Orderlines.PROD_ID
ORDER BY c DESC;
```

Comment: You shouldn't be storing `quantity` as a character value. Store it as a proper number (e.g. `integer`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is to use `dense_rank()`:

```
SELECT PROD_ID, c
FROM (SELECT PROD_ID, COUNT(*) AS c,
             DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) ASC) as seqnum_asc,
             DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum_desc
      FROM Orderlines
      GROUP BY Orderlines.PROD_ID
     ) o
WHERE seqnum_asc <= 2 OR
      seqnum_desc <= 2
ORDER BY c DESC;
```